# How to get data index from List Dart

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I have the list data like this

[image]

```
void main() {
  var animals = [
    {
      "0": ["cow", "chicken", "Fish"]
    },
    {
      "1": ["lamb", "Camel"]
    },
    {
      "2": ["Goat", "Cat"]
    }
  ];
  print(animals.length);
  for (var a in animals) {
for (final x in a.entries){
print (x.value)}
}

}
```

but I want to get data to become like this:

```
1. cow 
2. chicken
3. fish
1. lamb
2. camel
1. goat
2. cat
```

So, what can I do to get the output? Thank you
I have tried to use join, but it is just for making a new line. not get the index.

**Using x.value.join("\n")**

[image]

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using .indexWhere and use a filter that includes all of your data. ([https://www.kindacode.com/snippet/dart-flutter-get-the-index-of-a-specific-element-in-a-list/#:~:text=In%20Dart%2C%20the%20List%20class,that%20satisfies%20the%20given%20conditions.](https://www.kindacode.com/snippet/dart-flutter-get-the-index-of-a-specific-element-in-a-list/#:%7E:text=In%20Dart%2C%20the%20List%20class,that%20satisfies%20the%20given%20conditions.))

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  var animals = [
    {
      "0": ["cow", "chicken", "Fish"]
    },
    {
      "1": ["lamb", "Camel"]
    },
    {
      "2": ["Goat", "Cat"]
    }
  ];
  for(var i in animals) {
    for(var j in i.entries) {
      for(var k = 0; k < j.value.length;k++) {
        print("${k+1}. ${j.value[k]}"); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `List.asMap()` would enumerate the list into indexes as keys to each associated value in the same order the list was.

The following code generates the desired output. [Try running it on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ce897c2b239b36f53de3b935f7f141db):

```dart
void main() {
  var animals = [
    {
      "0": ["cow", "chicken", "Fish"]
    },
    {
      "1": ["lamb", "Camel"]
    },
    {
      "2": ["Goat", "Cat"]
    }
  ];
  for (final a in animals) {
    for (final x in a.values) {
      for (final y in x.asMap().entries) {
        print('${y.key + 1}. ${y.value}');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1. cow
2. chicken
3. Fish
1. lamb
2. Camel
1. Goat
2. Cat
```